# How to make images pop out?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a few images. If I need to make the images to pop-out once I click on it and make the background transparent,what would be the best way of doing this?

Comment: using jQuery modal box

Comment: any coding samples or website I could refer to?

Comment: try searching on Google :)

Comment: as like this https://jqueryui.com/dialog/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you could use a [lightbox](http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/).

(Click the example images to see if that's what you're looking for.)

Comment: Exactly what I meant. That is helpful :)

Comment: If lightbox itself doesn't have certain features that you would like, you can find lots of similar variants with slightly different functionality by [googling](https://www.google.com/search?q=best+lightbox). (I've heard people call them "lightboxes" whether or not they actually use the original lightbox plugin--that might help you search.)

Answer (score 0):

Jquery dialog box would also be useful please check this fiddle here

jsfiddle.net/db5SX/